# Do Int and Double share a common parent class in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, int, double

I'm wondering if there is an easier way to write these two initializers as a generic Initializer

```
public required init(_ value : Double) {
    super.init(value: value, unitType: unit)
}

public required init(_ value : Int) {
    let v = Double(value)
    super.init(value: v, unitType: unit)
}
```

Something like:

```
public init<T>(_value : T) {
    let v = Double(T)
    super.init(value: v, unitType: unit)
}
```

(which of course doesn't compile)

I've looked through the code of both Int and Double and am missing any real thing that ties them together.

Comment: They share many protocols in common – they're both `AbsoluteValuable`, `Comparable`, `IntegerLiteralConvertible`.  Check out [SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Double/hierarchy/) to get an easy look at the full hierarchy.  But to really answer this question requires more info about the class you are initializing – it really depends on what `value:` in `super.init` is.

Comment: It requires a Double to initialize, however, I figured I could wrap any class (including) double in a Double and it should work.

Comment: `Int` and `Double` are structs, not classes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the Swift header:

```
extension String : StringInterpolationConvertible {
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: String)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Character)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UnicodeScalar)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Bool)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Float32)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Float64)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UInt8)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int8)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UInt16)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int16)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UInt32)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int32)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UInt64)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int64)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: UInt)
    init(stringInterpolationSegment expr: Int)
}
```

Similarly:

```
func +(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
func +(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
func +(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
func +(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
func +(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
func +(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
func +(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
func +(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
func +(lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float
func +(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double
func +(lhs: Float80, rhs: Float80) -> Float80
```

If it were possible to write *one* generic function for *all* those different numeric types, they would have done it, surely. So the answer to your question must be No.

(And in any case they can hardly share a parent *class*, as they are not *classes*. They are structs.)

Now, of course, if only Int and Double are in question, *you* could extend Int and Double to adopt a common protocol and make that protocol the expected type...

Comment: This is a misleading answer.  It depends on the use case.  While these types  require their own addition operator, it is perfectly possible to define broad classes of operation across, say, all the integers, such as for example `func sum<S: SequenceType where S.Generator.Element: IntegerType>(seq: S) -> S.Generator.Element { return reduce(seq,0) { $0 + $1 } }`.  That said, there are few protocols that bridge between both integers and floats.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Actually I was just waiting for you to come along and give the _right_ answer. Please give it!

Comment: FYI: As of Swift 4.0 this protocol is deprecated.

Comment: @KirillTitov Does that mean one can not creae a string from a numeric type now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the type `SignedNumeric` with the `any` keyword.

An example for Swift 5.9:

```swift
let numbers: [any SignedNumeric] = [
  Double(0.0),
  Int(0),
]

for number in numbers {
  if let aDouble = number as? Double {
    print ("double value \(aDouble)")
  } else {
    print ("int value \(number)")
  }
}
```